# Encrypted rootfs on P2041 board

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt the rootfs on a bootable mSD on a P2041 board.

My main reference is the Arch-Linux guide for encrypted roots under the "Luks on a partition" section.

What I have done so far:

1. Created two partitions, one /boot and one / (root). Boot is
   unencrypted, root is encrypted
2. On host machine:
3. cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat --type luks1 $ROOTFS_PARTITION
4. cryptsetup open $ROOTFS_PARTITION $CRYPTO_LABEL
5. mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/$CRYPTO_LABEL
6. mount /dev/mapper/$CRYPTO_LABEL $MNT_ROOTFS
7. tar zxf $yocto_rootfs -C $MNT_ROOTFS
8. cryptsetup close $CRYPTO_LABEL
9. On target machine:
10. Added to kernel parameters:

    ```
    cryptdevice=UUID=$device-uuid:crypto_rootfs root=/dev/mapper/crypto_rootfs
    ```

But target machine waits for /dev/mapper/crypto_roots indefinitely as it seems not to be able to find and decrypt it.

Comment: How are you checking the UUID?

Comment: I am checking the UUID on the host machine when I mount the partition

Comment: Does yocto use an initramfs, and if so, which initramfs generating tool does it use?

Comment: No, I don't use any initramfs: that's the point I was double-checking, as the Arch Linux guide referred to mkinitcpio. I assume that same results could be reached using initramfs, am I correct?